# Postgresql 8.3 version needed for OpenSUSE

Tags: linux, postgresql, opensuse

I have installed OpenSUSE 12.1 installed on machine.
and i have  postgresql-contrib-8.3.11-0.1.i586.rpm,postgresql-devel-8.3.11-0.1.i586.rpm,   postgresql-docs-8.3.11-0.1.i586.rpm,postgresql-libs-8.3.11-0.1.i586.rpm,postgresql-server-8.3.11-0.1.i586.rpm..
I want to installed postgresql 8.3 version based on above packages..but when i installed with this command .it shows an error.

**opnsu121:/ # rpm -Uvh postgresql-server-8.3.11-0.1.i586.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        postgresql = 8.3 is needed by postgresql-server-8.3.11-0.1.i586**

Even i am not able to find postgresql 8.3 base version as i think the above one is update.i have gone  throgh the download.openSUSE.orf,ftp.openSUSE.org..
http://download.opensuse.org/update/11.0/rpm/i586/..
but not able to find what i need..so please help on this,

Comment: Why? It looks like OpenSUSE 12.1 ships with Pg 9.1.1. Why install 9.3? Are you trying to solve a compatibility problem? If so, perhaps post details? For old versions it's often easier to just compile them from source code anyway.

Comment: Um, I meant "why install 8.3", there being no 9.3 yet. See the answer posted for suggestions.

Comment: Also, note that the packages you're trying to install are not only an old major version, they're 7 patch releases behind. The current 8.3 is 8.3.18 and you're trying to install 8.3.11 . You'd be missing a lot of bug fixes if you used 8.3.11.

Comment: You probably need to go here (http://stackoverflow.com/users/970785/asha-koshti?tab=questions&sort=votes) and accept any good answers to your old questions; otherwise fewer people may answer new ones. Just so you know.

Comment: ye..i want to solve the issue as in one organization they are having policy not to upgrade above postgres8.3.14.so as our software was having check that whether system is having postgres8.4 or not..?..so i have created a new build after removing the check in my software,,so want to test on postgres8.3 SUSE linux,,,

Comment: Their policy is hopelessly misguided. It is vital to upgrade to the latest PostgreSQL minor release, eg 8.3.18 in this case. Such minor releases only contain bug fixes and are very, very conservative. They fix problems and should be applied.

Comment: As per my answer: in this case, build from source or use the EnterpriseDB installer. You can download the 8.3.14 sources if you really want, but it's the height of organisational stupidity to require you to custom-compile a specific version rather than use a well-tested existing distribution of the same thing with a few extra bug fixes. I realise your company may not listen to reason, though, so you might be stuck with going along with the stupid.

Comment: @craig Ringer..its not my company..we are distributing product to other company..so as they have this requirements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hurray...I got the answer..
I have got the package below:
postgresql-contrib-8.3.11-0.1.i586.rpm, postgresql-devel-8.3.11-0.1.i586.rpm,postgresql-docs-8.3.11-0.1.i586.rpm,postgresql-libs-8.3.11-0.1.i586.rpm,postgresql-server-8.3.11-0.1.i586.rpm from the below link:
http://download.opensuse.org/update/12.1/i586/

and the one more package which i have struggled to get is:

postgresql-8.3.11-0.1.i586.rpm with the following link:

http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17194424/dir/opensuse_11.x/com/postgresql-8.3.11-0.1.i586.rpm.html

with all above packages i have installed using..
**rpm -ivh packagename**
if there is a dependency then **rpm -ivh --nodeps packagename**

great..its done..

Comment: It's done FOR NOW. Next time the customer tries to update their server with YaST, the update might fail. Next time they try to upgrade it to a new release, the upgrade is quite likely to fail. This is unsafe and downright horrible. Do not use --nodeps. You should be installing the EnterpriseDB packages or building from source, not forcing RPMs from an old release to install unsafely.

Answer (score 4):

If at all possible, use `YaST` or whatever package manager SuSE uses to install the current version of PostgreSQL. From [the repository](http://download.opensuse.org/factory/repo/oss/suse/x86_64/) it looks like that's 9.1.1.

If you specifically need PostgreSQL 8.3, I'd recommend using the [distro-independent installer from EnterpriseDB](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload). That should work fine on SuSE 12.2. If your organisation has particularly restrictive and unsafe version policies that force you to use old versions with known bugs, you can get 8.3.14 for 32-bit Linux [here](http://www.enterprisedb.com/postgresql-8314-installers-linux32?ls=Crossover&type=Crossover) and 8.3.11 for 32-bit Linux [here](http://www.enterprisedb.com/postgresql-8311-installers-linux32?ls=Crossover&type=Crossover).

If you have issues with using the well-tested and known-to-work EnterpriseDB binary installer versions of PostgreSQL, your other option (and a good one) is to install from source code. Download the [PostgreSQL 8.3.18 sources](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/v8.3.18/) from the [FTP site](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/source/), then:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/postgresql93
sudo chown `id -un` /opt/postgresql93
./configure --prefix=/opt/postgresql93
make
make install
```

after which you can use `/opt/postgresql93/bin/initdb` (see [initdb manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-initdb.html)) to create a database and `/opt/postgresql93/bin/pg_ctl` (see [pg_ctl manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html)) to start/stop it, as per the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/).

Don't try to force packages from an old version of SuSE to install on your new version. It'll probably result in an increasing tree of dependencies and end in pain.

If at all possible, try to convince your company that their policy of requiring a specific *minor* version (eg 8.4.14 not just "8.4.x") of PostgreSQL is unsafe and counterproductive. They're forcing you to do dirty hacks or hand-compile unique, custom installs just for your setup in order to *avoid using well tested builds that contain extra bug fixes*. Requiring approval before upgrading from 8.3 to 8.4/9.0/9.1/etc makes sense as there are feature and backward compatibility changes that require careful testing, but requiring approval before upgrading from 8.3.14 to 8.3.18 is counterproductive. Minor version upgrades of PostgreSQL [are very conservative](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/); you should stay up to date with the latest minor release.